# Add to home screen doesn't appear on my angular apps

Tags: node.js, angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have an angular app running on angular 7 and i'm trying to turn it on PWA, i installed pwa 0.6.8 and everything is working (in localhost) except the add to home screen who doesn't show up when i am running it on galaxy S5 from the google dev tolls

When i run the audit it says that it is installable for the user : 
[Result of the audit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0c10.png)

here is my index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>BSJP</title>
      <base href="/">

       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
     scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
   crossorigin=""/>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="144x144" href="assets/icons/icon-144x144.png">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
   crossorigin=""></script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

my manifest :

```
{
  "name": "mvp-front",
  "short_name": "BouffeSqueJtePrepare",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

and ngsw.config.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

what am i missing ?

Thank you

Comment: A2HS should work once you have it on a HTTPS host and Lighthouse says it is installable.

Answer (score 1):

A web app can only be added to a homescreen when the site is visited at least twice, with at least five minutes between visits.

This guide tells you how you can simulate those events for development: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/progressive-web-apps

Comment: thank for your answer. 

Yeah i have seen this, but my problem is that the add to home screen link in indentity section never appear, even on the link given by the guide : 
https://events.google.com/io2016/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try to host the project in `Firebase` (you can also choose another provider).

It is  free and it gives already HTTPS out of the box. You can create a project in Firebase and [deploy](https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-an-angular-cli-app-to-production-with-firebase) the solution in less than 10 minutes. Then you can test for real with any mobile device whether you app prompts for a A2HS.

I started writing a series of articles about PWAs, if you are interested to learn more about it you can have a look. The second post covers exactly the A2HS topic: [How to install a PWA on a user's device](https://dev.to/paco_ita/install-a-pwa-on-the-user-s-device-step-2-27pa).

Answer (score 1):

Add to home screen will appear if your application fullfills following criteria

1. manifest.json
2. app hosted over https server : eg: you can use netlify
3. service worker with atleast one fetch event.

You can find the entire code for it at

https://github.com/rohan12patil/pwa/tree/A2HS

demo at
https://newpwa.netlify.com

The code is basic & you can easily understand & integrate in your angular app